# Could detect windows touch keyboard has popped up or not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Currently, I can open & close the windows touch keyboard,

I don't know how to detect the touch keyboard is popped up or not,

so I try to get windows style value,

when I click the button at the top-right corner, to hiding the touch keyboard, please reference this image

[image]

the windows style value is the same as I did not hide the touch keyboard,

Is there any way to detect this situation?

---Test code as below -------------------------------------------------------

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CloseWindowsTouchKeyboard();
        }

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenWindowsTouchKeyboard();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseWindowsTouchKeyboard();
        }

        private void btnGetWindowLong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetWindowLong();
        }

        private const string IPTIP_MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS_NAME = "IPTip_Main_Window";
        private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
        private const uint SC_CLOSE = 61536;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        public static void OpenWindowsTouchKeyboard()
        {
            string strFilePath = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe";
            if (!File.Exists(strFilePath))
            {
                return;
            }
            Process.Start(strFilePath);
        }

        public static void CloseWindowsTouchKeyboard()
        {
            IntPtr TouchhWnd;
            TouchhWnd = FindWindow(IPTIP_MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS_NAME, null);
            if (TouchhWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return;
            }
            PostMessage(TouchhWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
        }

        public static void GetWindowLong()
        {
            IntPtr tKeyboardHandle = FindWindow(IPTIP_MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS_NAME, null);
            if (tKeyboardHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                uint iStyle = GetWindowLong(tKeyboardHandle, GWL_STYLE);
                Console.WriteLine($"iStyle: {iStyle}");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to utilize ComImport to define interfaces manually:

```cs
    [ComImport, Guid("228826af-02e1-4226-a9e0-99a855e455a6")]
    class ImmersiveShellBroker { }

    [ComImport, Guid("9767060c-9476-42e2-8f7b-2f10fd13765c")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IImmersiveShellBroker
    {
        void M();
        IInputHostManagerBroker GetInputHostManagerBroker();
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("2166ee67-71df-4476-8394-0ced2ed05274")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IInputHostManagerBroker { void GetIhmLocation(out Bounds rect, out DisplayMode mode); }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Bounds { public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom; }

    enum DisplayMode { None = 0, Floating = 2, Docked = 3 }
```

Then you can use them to check the touch keyboard display mode like so,

```cs
IImmersiveShellBroker broker = (IImmersiveShellBroker)(new ImmersiveShellBroker());
IInputHostManagerBroker inputHost = broker.GetInputHostManagerBroker();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(broker);

// if mode != DisplayMode.None then the keyboard is open
DisplayMode mode;
inputHost.GetIhmLocation(out _, out mode);
```

you can also cache the inputHost somewhere, but it's not necessary.